# Is it possible to manually rotate point clouds in RViz?

Tags: ros, kinect, rviz, ros-hydro, static-transform-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been working with some Kinects in `Rviz` and recently found the ability to use `static_transform_publisher` to create the necessary transforms between pointclouds so that it will allow me to display multiple point clouds at once.  Since `camera_pose_calibration` doesn't work in Hydro, I'm going to try to align them manually as a first step.  However, I was wondering if there was a way to rotate/translate point clouds in `Rviz` itself that I may have missed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131491/is-it-possible-to-manually-rotate-point-clouds-in-rviz?/) by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 429 on 2014-02-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mrtpk](https://answers.ros.org/users/38090/mrtpk/) on 2018-10-18**:
Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think this functionality is there out of the box. It might be easily implemented with interactive markers as a small node providing a 6DoF marker that directly controls a tf transform. This seems like an obvious little tool, so maybe you are in luck and someone has hacked together such a utility already.

**Edit:** Another idea would be hijacking the joint_state_publisher [1] GUI by writing a small URDF file with a joint between your cameras (possible a floating joint, but I dont know how the joint_state_publisher GUI handles these. Use this in combination with robot_state_publisher to get the /tf transforms.

[1] http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1